# Consolidating rows in SQL using CASE statement

Tags: sql-server, case

This is my current results of my query:
[image]

I need to rename the Trimester column to 'FirstTri', if the Trimester value is either 'FirstVisit1HealthCenter' or 'FirstVisit1OtherProvider'. If the values in the Trimester column are 'FirstVisit2HealthCenter' or 'FirstVisit2OtherProvider' then the Trimester column is 'SecondTri'. Same with the rows with a '3'.  The column will be 'ThirdTri'.

The values in the column 'First Visit with Health Center' are not null, those values need to be returned.  The values in the column 'First Visit with Other  Provider' that are not null also need to be kept.

[image]

This is the `SELECT` statement that I have but it keeps returning the values that are `NULL`

```
SELECT DISTINCT 6 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Trimester) AS Line, 
        CASE WHEN Trimester IN ('FirstVisit1HealthCenter', 'FirstVisit1OtherProvider') THEN 'First Trimester'
             WHEN Trimester IN ('FirstVisit2HealthCenter', 'FirstVisit2OtherProvider') THEN 'Second Trimester'
             WHEN Trimester IN ('FirstVisit3HealthCenter', 'FirstVisit3OtherProvider') THEN 'Third Trimester' END AS EarlyEntry, 
        CASE WHEN [First Visit with Health Center] IS NOT NULL THEN [First Visit with Health Center] END AS [First Visit with Health Center],
        CASE WHEN [First Visit with Other Provider] IS NOT NULL THEN [First Visit with Other Provider] END AS [First Visit with Other Provider] 
--SELECT *
FROM #tblSubResult
```

How do I **NOT** return the rows that are NULL but only return 3 rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could could make your query a sub query and Sum the columns:

```
select EarlyEntry, 
sum([First Visit with Health Center]) as [First Visit with Health Center], 
sum([First Visit with Other Provider]) as [First Visit with Other Provider]  
from (
        SELECT DISTINCT 6 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Trimester) AS Line, 
                CASE WHEN Trimester IN ('FirstVisit1HealthCenter', 'FirstVisit1OtherProvider') THEN 'First Trimester'
                     WHEN Trimester IN ('FirstVisit2HealthCenter', 'FirstVisit2OtherProvider') THEN 'Second Trimester'
                     WHEN Trimester IN ('FirstVisit3HealthCenter', 'FirstVisit3OtherProvider') THEN 'Third Trimester' END AS EarlyEntry, 
                CASE WHEN [First Visit with Health Center] IS NOT NULL THEN [First Visit with Health Center] END AS [First Visit with Health Center],
                CASE WHEN [First Visit with Other Provider] IS NOT NULL THEN [First Visit with Other Provider] END AS [First Visit with Other Provider] 
        --SELECT *
        FROM #tblSubResult) a
        group by EarlyEntry
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks!